# How to do authorization in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

now i write the flask login application using `flask_login` library and in this part is work fine, but now what i want is how can i specify the user who can access or not access to the route, and this is my code.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_required, login_user, current_user, logout_user

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'thisissecretekey'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///sites.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

login_manager = LoginManager(app)
 
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(user_id)

# ----------- Database Tables -------------
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(40))
    role_code = db.Column(db.String(30), db.ForeignKey('roles.role_code'))

    def get_id(self):
           return (self.id)

class Roles(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'roles'
    role_code = db.Column(db.String(40), primary_key = True)
    role_name = db.Column(db.String(50))

# --------------- Routes ----------------
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        user = User.query.filter(User.username == username).first()
        if user and password == user.password:
            login_user(user)
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/index')
@login_required
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/logout', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('login'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

For example i have this data in database.

**Roles table**

`Roles(role_code='a', role_name='Admin')`

`Roles(role_code='o', role_name='Operator')`

**User table**

`User(username='tom', password='pass', role_code='a')`

`User(username='frank', password='pass', role_code='e')`

If i want specify the `/index` route can only access by user who have `role_code` equal to `a` or `Admin`, what is the best way can i do that?

Comment: `if current_user.role_code not in ['a','Admin']: return ("Not Authorized",404)`

Answer (score 2):

`flask-login` provides `@login_required` decorator so you need to create your own `@admin_required` decorator, the code below is taken from `flask-base` a starter project (github [repo](https://github.com/hack4impact/flask-base) )

```
[..]
from functools import wraps

[..]

class Permission:
    GENERAL = 0x01
    ADMINISTER = 0xff

[..]

def permission_required(permission):
    """Restrict a view to users with the given permission."""

    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
            if not current_user.can(permission):
                abort(403)
            return f(*args, **kwargs)

        return decorated_function

    return decorator


def admin_required(f):
    return permission_required(Permission.ADMINISTER)(f)
```

then you can decorate `/index` route with `@admin_required`, please note the **order** how to call decorators:

```
@app.route('/index')
@login_required
@admin_required
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

and in your template:

```
<table class="ui compact definition table">
  <tr><td>Full name</td><td>{{ '%s %s' % (user.first_name, user.last_name) }}</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Email address</td><td>{{ user.email }}</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Account type</td><td>{{ user.role.name }}</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this is a great answer ... but does not match the implementation pattern the OP used ... (ie role is a text field in OP's models, and the Role class is to define the long name for some single letter code) (although you could easily edit your example to match OP's case)